# Show column "Location" only for users with role full control in page layout and edit form

Tags: page-layout, edit-form

Is it possible to show the control with id "Location" only if the current user has full control permissions?

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel ID="EditModePanel1" runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Edit" CssClass="edit-mode-panel roll-up">
                    <span>Titel: </span><span>
                    <SharePointWebControls:TextField runat="server" FieldName="Title" />
                    </span>

                    <span>Geef een locatie voor dit artikel: </span>
                    <span>
                        <Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl ID="TaxonomyFieldControl1" FieldName="Location" runat="server">
                        </Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl>
                    </span>


                    <span>Content: </span>
                    <span>
                        <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" runat="server"/>
                    </span>



</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

I would like to do that in the page layout and edit form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'd want to wrap in a control like this:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="ManageWeb">
    <span>Geef een locatie voor dit artikel: </span>
                    <span>
                        <Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl ID="TaxonomyFieldControl1" FieldName="Location" runat="server">
                        </Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl>
                    </span>
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

[Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPSecurityTrimmedControl_properties(v=office.14).aspx)